# Modifying data in R

Tags: r

I have data set in the following format

```
Ids                             Country
98643                           USA
98175 98181 98185 98191 98194   AUSTRALIA
98570                           GERMANY
98848 98824                     ITALY
```

and what I need is the data in the following format

```
Ids Country
98643   USA
98175   AUSTRALIA
98181   AUSTRALIA
98185   AUSTRALIA
98191   AUSTRALIA
98194   AUSTRALIA
98570   GERMANY
98848   ITALY
98824   ITALY
```

If anyone could help me in transforming the data in R programming it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyr` -

```
yourdf %>% separate_rows(Ids, sep = " ")
```